# How to prove that any number from $0$ to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ can be obtained as sum of subset of set {$1,2,3, ... ,n$}

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, pigeonhole-principle

I tried to prove it using pigeon hole principle (by proving that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ distinct numbers can be obtained as sum).

Edit :
some good answers are already posted. Thanks to all of them. Do share a proof using different methods . It's sad that i cannot accept more than one answer.

Comment: There are $2^n-1$ nonempty subsets.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee yes but all of them may not give distinct sum . (1+2+3) = (4+1) .It doesn't proves that all sums obtained will be less than or equal to $n*(n+1)/2$

Comment: $n\over 2$ of the 2 element subsets have sum $n+1$ I know. I was giving a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By induction.  Easy to confirm for small $n$.

Suppose the claim is true for $n-1$, so we can get every number from $0$ to $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ just using $\{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}$.  Now we add the element $n$ and we seek to get the numbers from $\frac {n(n-1)}2+1$ to $\frac {n(n+1)}2$.  But $$\frac {n(n+1)}2-\frac {n(n-1)}2=n$$ so subtracting $n$ from any of those numbers gets you into the previously solved range, so we are done.

Comment: Induction was second thought after i failed to prove using pigeon hole principle.But i was tired and thus posted .Thanks your prove is short and nice .Do share a proof using pigeon hole principle if you can !

Comment: I don't see how the pigeon hole principle is relevant here.  It's easy to get a single number in multiple ways, as in $1+2=3$, so there's no obvious restriction on the number of pigeons that can fit into a single hole, as it were.

Comment: Yeah correct ..

Answer (score 1):

The pigeonhole principle can't tell you that all of the holes are filled.  Induction is the way to go.

---

All of the numbers from $0$ to $1$ can be formed as sums of subsets of $\{1\}$.

Now, assume that $k\in \mathbb N$ is such that all the numbers from 0 through $\frac {k(k+1)}2$ can be expressed as the sum of a subset of $1..k$.  Now, let $n$ between $0$ and $\frac {(k+1)(k+2)}2$.

By induction, the proposition follows.

- If $n\le \frac {k(k+1)}2$, then it can be expressed as a sum of a subset of $1..k$ which is clearly also a subset of $1..(k+1)$
- If $\frac {k(k+1)}2<n\le \frac {(k+1)(k+2)}2$, then consider $n'=n-(k+1)$.  $0\le n'\le \frac {k(k+1)}2$, so $n'$ can be expressed as a sum of a subset of $1..k$.  Appending $(k+1)$ to that subset gives a subset of $1..(k+1)$ that adds to $n$.

Comment: pigeonhole principle can be used .See maximum is n*(n+1)/2 and thus we have total n*(n+1)/2 holes (from 1 till n*(n+1)/2) . So if we some how prove that there are at least n*(n+1)/2  distinct sum of subsets then we are done !

Comment: Your proof is also nice . its sad that we can accept only one answer ...

Comment: @Shawn lol, it's all right.  I upvoted lulu's solution too!  ^_^

Comment: Strong form of pigeonhole principle might work better.

Answer (score 1):

$m\in\mathbb{N}^+$ can be written as a sum of distinct elements from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ iff the coefficient of $x^m$ in
$$ (1+x)(1+x^2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1+x^n)$$
is positive. On the other hand all the coefficients of 
$$ q_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x^k)$$
are positive. This can be shown by induction: the claim holds for $n=1$ and 
$$ q_{n+1}(x) = (1+x^{n+1})q_n(x), $$
so for any $m\in\left[0,\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]$ we have
$$ [x^m] q_{n+1}(x) \geq [x^m]q_n(x) > 0 $$
and for any $m\in\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1,\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right]$ we have
$$ [x^m] q_{n+1}(x) = [x^{m-n-1}] q_n(x) > 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Induction.

If $n>2$ then $n \le \frac {(n-1)n}2$ and $\frac {n(n+1)}2 - n = \frac {(n-1)n}2$.

Base Cases:

$n=0,1,2$ then $0 = \sum_{k \in \emptyset} k$

$n=1,2$ then $1=\sum_{k\in\{1\}} k$.

$n=2$ then $2=\sum_{k\in \{2\}}k$ and $3=\sum_{k\in \{1,2\}} k$.

Induction:

Assume true for $k = n-1$. That is, every integer, $m$ from $0$ to $\frac {(n-1)n}2$ is the sum of a subset of $\{1,2,....,n-1\}$.  Call such a subset $K_m$.

Now if $m \le \frac {(n-1)n}2$ then $m = \sum\limits_{k\in K_m\subset \{1,....,n-1\} \subset\{1,....,n\}} k$

And if $\frac {(n-1)n}2 < m \le \frac {n(n+1)}2$ then $0 \le m -n \le \frac {n(n-1)}2$.  So there is a set $K_{m-n}\subset \{1,2,....,n-1\}$ where $m-n = \sum\limits_{k\in K_{m-n}} k$.

And so $m = n + \sum\limits_{k\in K_{m-n}} k= \sum\limits_{k\in K_{m-n}\cup \{n\}\subset \{1,2,....n\}} k$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the sum of first $n$ natural numbers is $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

So  ,

$$1+2+3+4+...+n =\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

By rearranging , we can show that :

$$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} -1 = 2+3+4+..+n$$
$$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} -2 = 1+3+4+..+n$$
$$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} -3 = 1+2+3+..+n$$
$$\vdots$$

Comment: This is 'argument' is using what needs to be proven. Thus, it is not a proof.

Comment: Will you *elaborate* on your previous comment ?

Comment: It is you who would need to elaborate if you want to claim that there is a proof there. The onus is on the prover. Note that there aren't really ... in proofs.Try to complete the 'rearranging' for the missing values. All the argument is contained there. Claiming that it can be completed is exactly the statement that needs to be proven.

Comment: The question asks to prove that all numbers less than $n(n+1)/2$ can written as sum of subset of $\{1,2,3,..,n \}$ . My answer is clearly not based on this claim.

Comment: Right ... Well, then you need more training on what constitutes a proof.

Comment: Just replace the ... by actual words and you will see that all needed for a proof is missing. What the ... is saying is that there exists a 'rearranging' such that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-K=\sum(\text{ some numbers between }1\text{ and }n)$ for all $4\leq K\leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. This claim, is the same as the original problem except for the three cases that are actually written $K=1,2$ and $3$.